# How to replace each letter in a string with a consecutive letter with increasing offset?

Tags: python, string

Suppose the word is `"CAT"` and I want the output to be `"DCW"`. Where the `C` changes to the next letter `D` and the `A` changes into the ***second*** next letter from `A` to `C` and the `T` changes into the ***third*** next letter from `T` to `W`.

I am on the first step here:

```
a = input("Enter a letter: ")
a = chr(ord(a) + 1)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the word:

```
word = 'CAT'
result = ''
for i, a in enumerate(word,1):
    result += chr(ord(a) + i)
print(result)

# alternatively, same loop as list comprehension
print(''.join(chr(ord(a) + i) for i, a in enumerate(word,1)))
```

Out:

```
DCW
DCW
```

Comment: Or, use `enumerate(word, 1)` and no need for that `+ 1`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import string
a =input("Enter a letter: ")
r=''
for i,e in enumerate(a,1):
   r=r+string.ascii_lowercase[string.ascii_lowercase.index(e.lower())+i]
print(r.upper())
```

or in one line like this :

```
print(''.join(list(string.ascii_lowercase[string.ascii_lowercase.index(e.lower())+i] for i,e in enumerate(a,1) )).upper())
```

**Note**: in Python 2, `string.ascii_lowercase`  is  `string.lowercase`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called Caesar cypher, but the offset changes with the character's position:

```
    def encrypt(text):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(text)):
        char = text[i]
        if (char.isupper()):
            result += chr((ord(char) -65) % 26 + 65 + i + 1)
        else:
            result += chr((ord(char) - 97) % 26 + 97 + i + 1)
    return result

print(encrypt(input()))
```

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cryptography_with_python/cryptography_with_python_caesar_cipher.htm